# How do I turn off the linker?

Tags: xamarin, rider

The [Linking on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) document describes how to turn off the linker in Visual Studio:

> The primary mechanism for controlling the linker is the Linker
> Behavior (Linking in Visual Studio) drop-down within the Project
> Options dialog box.

How do I turn off the linker using JetBrains Rider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For Android

Android linker settings are available under `YourAppName.Android > Properties > Release | AnyCPU`.

[image: Android linker settings]

#### For iOS

iOS linker settings are available under `YourAppName.iOS > Properties > Release | iPhone`.

[image: ios Linker settings]